# React-Router v6: Login and Signup Pages Rendered on Home Page's Navbar Component Instead of Separate Pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm currently working on a React application using React Router v6 for routing. I have a `Navbar` component that contains navigation links for the login and signup pages. However, when I click on these links, the content of the login and signup pages is displayed on the same page as the Navbar component.

Here is the code for reference:
App.js file

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup/>} />
      </Routes>
      </Router>
      <Hero></Hero>
      <Analytics></Analytics>
      <Cards></Cards>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

NavBar.jsx File

```
  return (
    <div className='flex justify-between items-center h-24 max-w-[1240px] mx-auto px-4 text-white'>
      <h1 className='w-full text-3xl font-bold text-[#00df9a]'>E</h1>
      <ul className='hidden md:flex'>
        <li className='p-4'>Home</li>
        <li className='p-4'>
          <Link to="/login">
            <button className='bg-[#00df9a] rounded-md font-medium px-4 py-0.4 text-black'>
              Login
            </button>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className='p-4'>
          <Link to="/signup">
            <button className='bg-[#00df9a] rounded-md font-medium px-4 py-0.4 text-black'>
              GetStarted
            </button>
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div onClick={handleNav} className='block md:hidden'>
        {!nav ? <AiOutlineClose size={20}/> : <AiOutlineMenu size={20}/>}
      </div>
      <div className={!nav ? 'fixed left-0 top-0 w-[60%] h-full border-r border-r-gray-900 bg-[#000300] ease-in-out duration-500' : 'fixed left-[-100%]' }>
        <h1 className='w-full text-3xl font-bold text-[#00df9a] m-4'>E</h1>
        <ul className='uppercase p-4'>
          <li className='p-4 border-b border-gray-600'>Home</li>
          <li className='p-4 border-b border-gray-600'>
            <Link to="/login">
              <button className='bg-[#00df9a] rounded-md font-medium px-4 py-0.4 text-black'>
                Login
              </button>
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className='p-4 border-b border-gray-600'>
            <Link to="/signup">
              <button className='bg-[#00df9a] rounded-md font-medium px-4 py-0.4 text-black'>
                Get Started
              </button>
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

The problem is that the login and signup page content is being displayed directly under the Navbar on the same page. I want these pages to be rendered separately when their respective links in the `Navbar` are clicked.

How can I ensure that the login and signup pages are rendered as separate pages and not on the same page as the `Navbar` component?

Comment: Where exactly are you rendering these components that you are "linking" to? We can't address issues in code we can't see. Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese Apologies for the incomplete code.
I want the login,sign up page elements to be rendered on a new Blank page
but as you can see in the picture I provided they get rendered onto the NavBar of the home page.

Comment: The image isn't very good since it's all black with some buttons and input fields, it's nearly impossible to see any UI boundaries. The `Navbar` also isn't rendering the routes. The routes are rendered below the navbar. Are you say that you ***don't*** want the navbar to render when on either of the `"/login"` of `"/signup"` routes?

Comment: @DrewReese My intention is to have the Navbar component render only on Home page. However, I want the login and signup pages to render as separate pages, not as components within the home page. Currently, when I click on the 'Login' or 'Get Started' buttons in the Navbar, The url path is updated to localhost:3000/login or signup and the login and signup forms are displayed on the home page itself, which is not the desired behavior. Instead, I'd like these forms to open on separate pages, maintaining the Navbar's presence across all pages.

Comment: You are only rendering two "pages": "login" and "signup". What do you consider to be the "home" page?

Comment: @DrewReese Currently I am keeping home page normal I have kept some text, home page is built in parts which include navbar, Hero, Analytics , Cards, Footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the post and issue correctly, you want the `Login` and `Signup` components to be rendered on their own routes separate from the rest of the "home page" content, e.g. the `Hero`, `Analytics`, and `Cards` components.

Move these other components into a root-level "home page" route.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={(
              <>
                <Hero />
                <Analytics />
                <Cards />
              </>
            )}
          />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to *conditionally* render the `Navbar` and `Footer` only with specific routes then create a layout route component. Layout route components render some "common UI" and an `Outlet` for nested routes to render their content into.

Example:

```
const Layout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet />
    <Footer />
  </>
);

const Home = () => (
  <>
    <Hero />
    <Analytics />
    <Cards />
  </>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<Layout />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            {/* other routes with navbar and footer */}
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```